# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg({n^2\int_n^{n+1}{f(x)dx}\bigg)=1}$. $f:(4,\infty)\to \mathbb R, f(x) = \frac{1}{x(x-4)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$f:(4,\infty)\to \mathbb R, f(x) = \frac{1}{x(x-4)}$$
I need to prove the next limit.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg({n^2\int_n^{n+1}{f(x)dx}\bigg)=1}$$
Here is what I tried. Since I had no other clue how to go about it, I tried to solve the integral under the limit and it evaluates to $\frac{1}{4}\bigg(\ln{\frac{(n+1)(n+4)}{n(n+5)}}\bigg)$.
Now, the limit becomes:
$$\frac{1}{4}\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg({n^2\ln{\frac{(n+1)(n+4)}{n(n+5)}}\bigg)}$$ 
$$\frac{1}{4}\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg({n^2\ln{\frac{n^2+5n+4}{n^2+5n}}\bigg)}$$
And now the limit seems to be $0\cdot\infty$. I know that we can generally solve this case of limits by writing one term so that the limit becomes $\infty \cdot \infty$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$so then we can apply L'hopital, but I don't know how to write the limit in this case, mainly because of the $\ln$ term and I am really confused. Help me, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to compute the integral. Since $f(x)$ is bounded between $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\frac{1}{(n-4)^2}$ for any $x\in[n,n+1]$, the limit is trivially one by squeezing.

Answer (score 1):

MVT for integrals:

$\displaystyle{\int_{n}^{n+1}}f(x)dx=f(s)\int_{n}^{n+1}1dx=$

$\dfrac{1}{s(s-4)}\cdot 1,$where $s \in [n,n+1]$.

$n^2(\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n-3)}\cdot 1) \le$

$n^2\displaystyle{\int_{n}^{n+1}}f(x)dx\le $

$n^2(\dfrac{1}{n(n-4)}\cdot 1).$

Take the limit.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: This is squeeze theorem applied exactly like Jack explained just before, right?

Comment: Radu.Yes. MVT, and Squeeze theorem. Jack uses boundedness for the integrand, with MVT you pull the fact out.

Comment: I don't understand why do we need MVT here? Couldn't I just do $n^2f(n) \le n^2\int_n^{n+1}{f(x)} \le n^2f(n+1)$ and apply squeeze theorem?

Comment: Radu. Sure. A bit formal. Since $f(n+1) \le f(x)$, $x \in [n,n+1]$, $\int_{n}^{n+1}f(n+1)dx \le \int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

$ln(\frac  {n^{2}+5n+4} {n^{2}+5n})=\ln (1+\frac 4 {n^{2}+5n})=\frac 4 {n^{2}+5n}+o(\frac  1 {n^{4}})$. Since $\frac 1 4 n^{2}(\frac 4 {n^{2}+5n}) \to 1$ we are done.

I have used the fact that $\ln (1+x) =x+o(x^{2})$ as $x \to 0$.